# Regex to match from 0.0 to 150.0 (including floating point)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem: i should match values from 0.0 to a specific double value (for example, i should match from 0.0 to 150.00 including value as 12, 21.23213, 149.111)

anyone can help me?

i tried everything.

i used this regexp for match by 0.0 to 60.0 but it doesn't work

```
(^0(\.[0-9]+)?$|^[1-9]{1}(\.[0-9]+)?$|^[1-5]{1}[0-9]{1}(\.[0-9]+)?$|^60$)
```

with 123 it doesn't work

thank you in advance

Marco

Comment: Why not just turn it into a float and check its numeric value?

Comment: PLEASE, FOR THE LOVE OF GOD, DO NOT USE A REGEX! AAAAAAGH!

Answer (score 14):

Don't use a regex - use [`Number`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_Number.asp), check it's a number with [`isNaN`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isNaN.asp), then compare values using `<=` and `>=`.

e.g.

```
var your_val = "3.05";
var your_val_num = Number(your_val);
if (!isNaN(your_val_num) && your_val_num >= 0 && your_val_num <= 150) {
  // do something
}
```

<sup>N.B. I've changed my answer to use `Number` rather than `parseFloat`, per AndyE's comment, and to check for `NaN` before doing numerical comparisons, per lincolnk's comment.</sup>

Comment: +1, but I would use `+` or *Number()* rather than *parseFloat()*, which would parse something like "149.5grams" as *149* and return *true* on the *if* statement.

Comment: should there be a call to `isNan` in there somewhere?

Comment: I've edited your post to change *isNAN* to *isNaN*.  However, you don't *really* need it because `NaN >= 0 && NaN <= 150` will always be false anyway :-) The OP might want it for performing a different action if isNaN() returns true, though.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with the other answers: regex is a poor way to do numeric comparisons.

If you *really* have to, either:

- because a dumb framework you're stuck with only allows regex checks, or
- you need extra decimal precision that a JavaScript Number can't provide (as JavaScript has no built-in Decimal type)... this won't be the case for comparing against the whole numbers 0 and 150 though

then:

```
^0*(                    // leading zeroes
150(\.0+)?|             // either exactly 150
1[0-4]\d(\.\d+)?|       // or 100-149.9*
\d{0,2}(\.\d+)?         // or 0-99.9*
)$
```

(newlines/comments added for readability, remove to use.)

This doesn't support E-notation (150=1.5E2) but should otherwise allow what normal JS Number parsing would.

Answer (score 3):

forget regex - just check if(parseFloat(x)=<150 && parseFloat(x)>=0)