# Regular expression for checking the range of numeric values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, regex, validation

I want to have a range between 0 to 65536 , what would be the regular expression for that?

Comment: Using a regular expression to check if number falls in a range is like using a hammer to open an orange.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use a regular expression.

```
if(i >= 0 && i <= 65536)
```

Comment: @mazhar: JQuery changes neither the fact that regexps are not suited for this nor does it change if statements.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression really isn't well suited to this sort of validation. [Gareth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708839/asp-net-mvc-range-check-regular-expression/3708852#3708852) provides a much more sensible solution.

If, for some reason, *you absolutely have to use a regex* then it will probably look something like this:

```
^(?:[0-5]?[0-9]{1,4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-6])$
```

Comment: No wait, the other thing. Horrific ;) I suppose it needed to be seen to compare the difference though

Answer (score 1):

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667953/regex-to-match-from-0-0-to-150-0-including-floating-point), which asks pretty much the same thing, and got pretty much the same answer. (ie don't use regex for this!)